Sampling multiple masked tokens through Metropolis–Hastings
I'm trying to replicate the finding of the the publication "Exposing the Implicit Energy Networks behind Masked Language Models via Metropolis-Hastings" for obtaining the joint distribution of multiple masked values in a BERT-like model. The central algorithm is the following:

Given the somewhat complex notation within the manuscript, my current minimal working code looks like that:
from typing import Sequence
import numpy as np
from copy import copy

LENGTH = 5
MASK_TOKEN = 42

def forward(sequence: Sequence[int]) -> np.ndarray:
    # Placeholder: Run the forward pass and get the unormalized logits
    return np.asarray([[0.2, 0.7, 0.1]] * len(sequence))

def energy_function(sequence: Sequence[int]):
    # That should be E_raw as specified in the paper.
    values = []
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        sequence_new = copy(sequence)
        sequence_new[i] = MASK_TOKEN
        values.append(forward(sequence_new))
        
    # QUESTION 1: HOW TO REDUCE THAT TO A SCALAR?
    return np.asarray(values).sum(axis=0)

x = np.argmax(forward([MASK_TOKEN] * LENGTH), axis=-1)
for e in range(100):
    for t in range(LENGTH):
        e_old = energy_function(x)
        
        # Mask the next token
        x_next = x.copy()
        w_old = x[t]
        x_next[t] = MASK_TOKEN

        # Sample the token
        # QUESTION 2: Is x_next correct here?
        prediction = forward(x_next)
        w_new = np.random.choice(a=prediction.shape[1], size=1, p=prediction[t])
        x_next[t] = w_new

        # Prepare everything for the calculation of the acceptance probability
        # QUESTION 3: ARE THOSE INDICES CORRECT?
        q1 = prediction[w_new]
        q2 = prediction[w_old]
        e_new = energy_function(x_next)

        acceptance_probability = min(1.0, 
            (np.exp(-e_old) * q2) / (np.exp(-e_new) * q1)
        )

        if np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) <= acceptance_probability:
            x = x_next

However, I'm now stuck at some details:

(Line 6) For obtaining the acceptance probability, we need E_raw or E_norm to return a scalar. However, we obtain a sum of raw logits or softmax'ed logits. I could not find any strategy in the paper for reducing the value to a single scalar. Where is my mistake in understanding the paper?
(Line 8) Should we really sample from X or from X' instead?
(Line 9) Do you understand that notation that we must use the sampled token ID for indexing the vectors, too?

